# Картинка не встраивается в контейнер

Tags: html, css

Хочу логотип разместить, но не могу подстроить его под контейнер. Она просто обрезается. Не знаю в чем дело, может быть потому что флекс-элемент?

```
<header>
         <div class="logo img">
            <a href="{% url 'index' %}"><img src="{% static 'app_vizitka/images/nast.jpg' %}" alt="логотип"></a>
         </div>
        <nav>
            {% for key, value in menu.items %}
            {% if title == value.title %}
            <span class="menu-item">{{ value.title }}</span>
            {% else %}
            <a class="menu-item" href="{% url value.url %}">{{ value.title }}</a>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </nav>
    </header>

header {
    height: 8vmin;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: #0d3563;
}

.logo {
    flex: 1;
    height: inherit;
}

.img img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

nav {
    flex: 5;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}

.menu-item {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

у тебя object-fit: cover; стоит, меняй на fill

```
.img img {
    object-fit: fill;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```